# Is std::regex thread safe?

Tags: c++, regex, thread-safety, std

Related to [Is a static boost::wregex instance thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263013/is-a-static-boostwregex-instance-thread-safe) but for the standarized version.  Can I call regex_search from several threads with the same regex object?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Claiming that [`std::regex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex) is thread-safe in every respect is a pretty bold statement. The C++11 standard does not make such guarantees for the regex library.

However, looking at the prototype of [`std::regex_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) shows that it it takes the `basic_regex` object as a const argument. This means that it is protected by the standard library's guarantee that the const modifier [implies thread-safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127379/does-const-mean-thread-safe-in-c11) of the function with respect to that argument.

In standardese, that is:

> **[17.6.5.9/1]**
>   This section specifies requirements that implementations shall meet to prevent data races (1.10). Every standard library function shall meet each requirement unless otherwise specified. Implementations may prevent data races in cases other than those specified below.
>
> **[17.6.5.9/3]**
>   A C++ standard library function shall not directly or indirectly modify objects (1.10) accessible by threads other than the current thread unless the objects are accessed directly or indirectly via the function’s *non-const* arguments, including `this`.

So, barring a bug in the implementation of the standard library that you use, it appears that calls to `std::regex_search` are thread-safe with respect to the `regex` object that is passed in.

---

**Other thoughts:**

Just because `std::regex_search` is re-entrant with respect to its `regex` argument does not mean that you are completely out of the water. Performing an operation that modifies a `regex` in a non-thread-safe manner at the same time as a thread-safe call such as `std::regex_search` is still undefined behaviour. `basic_regex`'s [assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex/operator%3D), [std::swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex/swap), and [`basic_regex::imbue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex/imbue) come to mind as non-thread-safe functions with respect to the `basic_regex` they operate on. Knowing this, it might be better for you to make a copy of the `regex` object, which should come at a minimal performance cost, for each thread to use/modify at its leisure.

Comment: `std::regex` instances represent a compiled regular expression and are *meant* to be re-used, since regex compilation is a costly process. Of course it would be stupid to swap/reassign an existing instance (be it `std::regex` or anything else) while other threads are already using it.

Answer (score 4):

While [Sean's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15753237/8701) is true of the standard, individual implementation may fall short.  VC++ 2013, at least, looks like it has [race conditions](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1253646/std-regex-copy-constructor-is-not-thread-safe) in its copy constructor and in a lazily evaluated variable.

Comment: According to that ticket, it should be fixed in the recently released VS2015.